# Trick a piece of software into thinking you are not using RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn

I usually RDP into my work machine that has all my software and the computing horsepower I need to do my work.

From there I connect to a VPN that allows me to access my test and production servers. This worked fine up until Friday when my hosting company pushed out a update that does not allow you to connect to the vpn while using RDP.

Is there a way to trick my hosting software into thinking that I am not using RDP?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: While's it's an interesting question, policy circumvention questions are off topic for the site.

Comment: Have you tried VNC, GoToMyPC, etc?  I've seen these used to circumvent licensing restrictions in software before.  Never used them of course.

Comment: This is not policy circumvention; this is getting around one of the numerous mistakes in their code. We pay more than 20k a month for hosting and it worked fine until Friday evening. It worked fine today when I went into the office. However, I cannot be in the office 24/7.

Comment: What VPN client are you using?  I've never heard of a VPN client caring if you're RDP'd into the computer or not.  What exactly happens when you try to do it?

Comment: If a VPN program is messging up RDP, I would guess that your problem is related to routing.  What VPN client, what exact error messages do you get when try to start the client and connect?  If the client connects fine, but you lose your RDP session, then you need to look at the route table.

Comment: techie007, AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client. It gives me a alert that says, "VPN establishment capability from a remote desktop is disabled. A VPN connection will not be established."

Answer (score 0):

I've just replied to this similar post:

[Windows: How to make programs think they're not running in a terminal server session?](https://superuser.com/questions/301583/windows-how-to-make-programs-think-theyre-not-running-in-a-terminal-server-ses/1128979#1128979)

Basically the methods that change the value of the environment variable or the registry don't work for me. So at last the simple solution is to use Parallel Access instead of Microsoft RDP whenever I want to use the program that I want to trick.